# User is not admin and does not have permissions to use host bind mounts for resource

Tags: docker, kubernetes, workflow, argoproj

I am trying run a argo `WorkflowTemplate` in kubernetes cluster in a custom namespace. Here are the quick specs.

```
namespace: appns
serviceaccount: default
# no Roles or RoleBindings
workflowtemplate
    spec.templates
      - container with volume mounts (config and secret)
      - dag
```

When the workflow is submitted, it spawns two containers, `main` and `wait`. The main container completes successfully but wait container ends with following error.

```
pods "my-app-batch-4lr8g-2581825101" is forbidden: user "system:serviceaccount:appns:default" is not an admin and does not have permissions to use host bind mounts for resource my-app-batch-batch-4lr8g-2581825101
```

I am perplexed about `does not have permissions to use host bind mounts`, what does it really mean?

What I tried with so far:

- Create `clusterrolebinding` with `clusterrole/admin` - `serviceaccount:appns:default`.
- Create `clusterrolebinding` with `clusterrole/cluster-admin` - `serviceaccount:appns:default`.
- Create `rolebinding` with with `clusterrole/admin` - `serviceaccount:appns:default`.
- Create `rolebinding` with with `clusterrole/cluster-admin` - `serviceaccount:appns:default`.
- Created a PSP, clusterrole and clusterrolebinding

```
 name:psp2
 privileged: true
 selinux, supplementalGroups, runAsUser, fsGroup => RunAsAny
 volumes:*

#and a ClusterRole as follows
 apiGroups: policy
 resources: podsecuritypolicies, 
 resourcesNames: 
   - psp2, 
   - privileged
 verbs: use

A clusterrolebinding with this policyclusterrole and serviceaccount:appns:default
```

The error message is still same.
Questions:

- What does that error message actually mean?
- How do I solve it? Or at least troubleshoot it.

Please feel free to ask for any further details. I intentionally did not pasted all the yamls to keep it brief and focused. I am a newbie in kubernetes, so really appreciate your advice.

Update:

- git gist: [Showing configmap](https://gist.github.com/samiron/4016a9b291f4bd24ddddf91022109f42)

Comment: I read that error message as saying "don't use `hostPath` type volumes" (for good reason; they're not reliable storage and you can misuse them to compromise the nodes).  Does that match something in your YAML files?

Comment: We are using configmap generator, then using `subPath` and `mountPath` to use that config map as a mount volume. I added a git gist link in the description for better clarification.

Comment: Is this resolved now? Also does the serviceaccount has to be mandatorily admin for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

My theory of this error is argo-workflows may be trying to write something out to the cluster when a job is completed.

`"system:serviceaccount:appns:default" is not an admin and does not have permissions to use host bind mounts for resource...`

could mean that the `default` user in the `appns` namespace wants to mount a filesystem on the cluster itself (`host bind mount`) and is unable to do so.

You probably don't want to write out to the cluster's filesystem anyway...

Argo workflows can be backed by a proper datastore like postgres.  To see an example of this, look at the postgres quickstart manifest:

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/manifests/quick-start-postgres.yaml

Specifically, look at the `persistence:` section of the `workflow-controller-configmap`.  This tells the workflow controller to use postgres for persistence.

When we tried this on a kubespray cluster, we ended up with a further error at the end of each workflow, something like:

`Error (exit code 1): pods "pod-name-42gh2-2603838711" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:appns:default" cannot patch resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "appns"`

This ended up being a missing `verb` on the roles for the `default` user in the `appns` namespace.  To fix it:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: pod-patcher-role
  namespace: appns
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods"]
    verbs: ["get", "patch", "list", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: "pod-patcher-role-role-binding"
  namespace: appns
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: "pod-patcher-role"
subjects:
  - apiGroup: ""
    kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: appns
```